# How does reduce function work?

Tags: python, reduce

As far as I understand, the reduce function takes a list `l` and a function `f`. Then, it calls the function `f` on first two elements of the list and then repeatedly calls the function `f` with the next list element and the previous result.

So, I define the following functions:

The following function computes the factorial.

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return fact(n-1) * n


def reduce_func(x,y):
    return fact(x) * fact(y)

lst = [1, 3, 1]
print reduce(reduce_func, lst)
```

Now, shouldn't this give me `((1! * 3!) * 1!) = 6`? But, instead it gives `720`. Why `720`? It seems to take the factorial of `6` too. But, I need to understand why.

Can someone explains why this happens and a work-around?

I basically want to compute the product of factorials of all the entries in the list.
The backup plan is to run a loop and compute it. But, I would prefer using reduce.

Comment: For a deeper understanding of *reduce*, see its pure python equivalent shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it:

I need to map the numbers to their factorials first and then call reduce with multiply operator.

So, this would work:

```
lst_fact = map(fact, lst)
reduce(operator.mul, lst_fact)
```

Comment: Well, that would sort of work. Your factorial function still computes the factorial of its input already, so your reduce isn't simply doing that.

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing it, and probably more "clean" than putting the factorial calculation inside the reduce function as some of the other answers suggested -- but either one will do what you want.

Answer (score 79):

The other answers are great. I'll simply add an illustrated example that I find pretty good to understand `reduce()`:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [47,11,42,13])
113
```

will be computed as follows:

[image]

([Source](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php)) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170506153354/http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php))

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is truly helpful. I have a quick question about the function in reduce: does it only take two parameters?

Comment: Yes. It expects 2 parameters.

Answer (score 33):

The easiest way to understand *reduce()* is to look at its pure Python equivalent code:

```
def myreduce(func, iterable, start=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if start is None:
        try:
            start = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise TypeError('reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value')
    accum_value = start
    for x in it:
        accum_value = func(accum_value, x)
    return accum_value
```

You can see that it only makes sense for your reduce_func() to apply the factorial to the rightmost argument:

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return fact(n-1) * n

def reduce_func(x,y):
    return x * fact(y)
```

With that small revision, the code produces *6* as you expected :-)

```
>>> lst = [1, 3, 1]
>>> myreduce(reduce_func, lst)
6
```

Comment: You have just made `reduce` naked!  but when `start=None` does not `myreduce((lambda x,y:x+y),[1,2,3,4])` returns 11 but it should have 10; I took `sum` as `func`

Comment: I think correction should look like `for x in iterable[1:]:`

Comment: The for loop should iterate over `it`, not `iterable`: `for x in it:`

Comment: For academic purposes only, a recursive implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77298563/).

Answer (score 10):

Your function calls `fact()` on *both arguments*. You are calculating `((1! * 3!)! * 1!)`. The workaround is to only call it on only the second argument, and pass `reduce()` an initial value of 1.

Answer (score 9):

From the [Python `reduce` documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node83.html),

> reduce(function, sequence) returns a single value constructed by calling the (binary) function on the first two items of the sequence, then on the result and the next item, and so on.

So, stepping through.  It computes `reduce_func` of the first two elements, `reduce_func(1, 3) = 1! * 3! = 6`.  Then, it computes `reduce_func` of the result and the next item: `reduce_func(6, 1) = 6! * 1! = 720`.

You missed that, when the result of the first `reduce_func` call is passed as input to the second, it's factorialized before the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, your `reduce_func` doesn't have the structure of a fold; it doesn't match your description of a fold (which is correct).

The structure of a fold is: `def foldl(func, start, iter): return func(start, foldl(func, next(iter), iter)`

Now, your `fact` function doesn't operate on two elements - it just calculates factorial.

So, in sum, you're not using a fold, and with that definition of factorial, you don't need to.

If you do want to play around with factorial, check out the y-combinator: http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html

If you want to learn about folds, look at my answer to this question, which demonstrates its use to calculate cumulative fractions: [creating cumulative percentage from a dictionary of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100612/creating-cumulative-percentage-from-a-dictionary-of-data/9101604#9101604)

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement factorial using reduce.

```
def factorial(n):
  return(reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,range(n+1)[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce executes the function in parameter#1 successively through the values provided by the iterator in parameter#2

```
print '-------------- Example: Reduce(x + y) --------------'

def add(x,y): return x+y
x = 5
y = 10

import functools
tot = functools.reduce(add, range(5, 10))
print 'reduce('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')=' ,tot

def myreduce(a,b):
    tot = 0
    for i in range(a,b):
        tot = tot+i
        print i,tot
    print 'myreduce('+str(a)+','+str(b)+')=' ,tot

myreduce(x,y)

print '-------------- Example: Reduce(x * y) --------------'

def add(x,y): return x*y
x = 5
y = 10

import functools
tot = functools.reduce(add, range(5, 10))
print 'reduce('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')=' ,tot

def myreduce(a,b):
    tot = 1
    for i in range(a,b):
        tot = tot * i
        print i,tot
    print 'myreduce('+str(a)+','+str(b)+')=' ,tot

myreduce(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the trivial examples, here is one where I find `reduce` to be actually quite useful:

Imagine an iterable of ordered `int` values, often with some runs of contiguous values, and that we'd like to "summarize" it as a list of tuples representing ranges. (Note also that this iterable could be a generator of a very long sequence --another reason to use `reduce` and not some operation on an in-memory collection).

```
from functools import reduce

def rle(a, b):
    if a and a[-1][1] == b:
        return a[:-1] + [(a[-1][0], b + 1)]
    return a + [(b, b + 1)]

reduce(rle, [0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 9], [])
# [(0, 3), (5, 6), (8, 10)]
```

Notice the use of a proper `initial` value (`[]` here) for `reduce`.

Corner cases handled as well:

```
reduce(rle, [], [])
# []

reduce(rle, [0], [])
# [(0, 1)]
```