# behaviour of reduce function in python

Tags: python, reduce

I am confused by the behavior of the `reduce` function.

- In the first example, I get the expected result: (1-1/2) * (1-1/3) = 1/3

  ```
  >>> reduce(lambda x, y: (1 - 1.0/x) * (1 - 1.0/y), [2,3])
  0.33333333333333337
  ```
- In the second example, I do not get the expected result:  (1-1/2) * (1-1/3) * (1-1/5) = 0.2666666

  ```
  >>> reduce(lambda x, y: (1 - 1.0/x) * (1 - 1.0/y), [2,3,5])
  -1.5999999999999996
  ```

Can someone please explain me what I am missing?

Comment: You understand that `reduce()` operates recursively, correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108855/how-does-reduce-function-work

Comment: In your second example you have three inputs. you need an additional

Comment: but applying reduce on lambda x, y: x * y   works on any size of list, right ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is a `map` and `reduce`:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> yourlist = [2, 3]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(lambda x: (1-1/x), yourlist))
0.33333333333333337

>>> yourlist = [2, 3, 5]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(lambda x: (1-1/x), yourlist))
0.2666666666666667
```

Because map converts each item to the `(1-1/item)` and then the `reduce` multiplies all of them.

#### Additional remarks:

Instead of the `lambda x, y: x * y` you could also use the faster [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.mul), for example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> yourlist = [2, 3, 5]
>>> reduce(operator.mul, map(lambda x: (1-1/x), yourlist))
0.2666666666666667
```

Thanks @acushner for pointing this out (in the comments).

#### What went wrong in your function

In this case it's actually quite easy to see what doesn't work, just use a named function and add some `print`s:

```
def myfunc(x, y):
    print('x = {}'.format(x))
    print('y = {}'.format(y))
    res = (1 - 1.0/x) * (1 - 1.0/y)
    print('res = {}'.format(res))
    return res

reduce(myfunc, [2, 3])
# x = 2
# y = 3
# res = 0.33333333333333337

reduce(myfunc, [2, 3, 5])
# x = 2
# y = 3
# res = 0.33333333333333337
# x = 0.33333333333333337
# y = 5
# res = -1.5999999999999996
```

So it uses the last result as "next" `x` value. That's why it worked for the length-2-list case but for more elements it simply doesn't apply the formula you want.

#### Alternative

Instead of using `map` and `reduce` you could also use a simple `for`-loop. It's much easier to get them right and most of the times they are more readable (and in some cases it's faster than `reduce`).

```
prod = 1
for item in yourlist:
    prod *= 1 - 1 / item
print(prod)
```

Yes, instead of 1 line it's now 4 lines long but it's easy to understand what is happening (but there might be some edge cases in which that doesn't behave like `reduce`, for example for empty inputs).

But I generally prefer simple loops over complicated `reduce`-operations but as always YMMV. :)

Comment: exactly. you could use `operator.mul` here as well

Comment: excellent thank you !!   I now understand my mistake ...
I need to wait 5 minutes before I can approve this as the answer !

Comment: @acushner Thanks for the suggestion. I added it to the answer.

Comment: `operator.mul` won't actually be any faster; it's just defined and available for import from the standard library.

Comment: @chepner Are you sure? I thought passing C functions (like `operator.mul`) to other C functions (like `reduce`) would result in less function-call overhead and thus better performance.

Comment: `operator.mul` isn't a C function; it is simply defined as `def mul(a, b): return a * b`.

Comment: (That said, I'm having trouble defining any tests to accurately measure the difference between the two, so I should adjust my claim to be that I wouldn't *expect* `operator.mul` to be any faster.)

Comment: @chepner Ah, you're talking about CPython without compiled `_operator` module? Normally the `_operator` module is compiled and then the function you mentioned is [replaced](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/operator.py#L412) with the [C function from the `_operator` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Modules/_operator.c#L71).

Comment: @MSeifert Thank you! I've been quite disappointed since I first looked at `operator.py` a few months ago, since I always thought it was exposing built-in functions. I never saw the `import _operator` at the bottom, expecting to have seen it near the top instead. (Having it at the bottom makes sense, now that I give it a moment's thought.)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I approve map/reduce answer above.

To understand why, read this:

> https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Reduce **recursively** calls your function on each element of your list with 2 arguments: an **accumulator** (value of last call) and current element.

So you get:

```
(1 - 1.0/( (1 - 1.0/2) * (1 - 1.0/3) )) * (1 - 1.0/5)
```

With:

```
reduce(lambda acc, x: (1 - 1.0/acc) * (1 - 1.0/x), [2,3,5])
>>-1.5999999999999996
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to why you get `-1.5999999999999996` as your result and for completeness we can compute it using https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce as our guide:

The first iteration will be (which takes our first 2 iterator values of `2` and `3` as `x` and `y`):

`(1 - 1.0 / 2) * (1 - 1.0 / 3)`

which becomes:

`0.5 * 0.6666666666666667`

which yields:

`0.33333333333333337`.

We then use `0.33333333333333337` to move on to our next iteration which takes this result as `x` and our next iteration number of `5` as `y`:

Therefore, our second iteration will be:

`(1 - 1.0 / 0.33333333333333337) * (1 - 1.0/5)`

which becomes:

`-1.9999999999999996 * 0.8`

which yields:

`-1.5999999999999996`

Answer (score -1):

In your second example you have 3 inputs. You need:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: (1 - 1.0/x) * (1 - 1.0/y)* (1 - 1.0/z),...
```

Comment: Why? The python docs page has 5 inputs, where did `z` come from?  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce - The left argument, x, is the accumulated value and the right argument, y, is the update value from the iterable