# Is it possible to sort a list with reduce?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I was given this as an exercise. I could of course sort a list by using **sorted()** or other ways from Python Standard Library, but I can't in this case. I **think** I'm only supposed to use **reduce()**.

```
from functools import reduce
arr = [17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 5, 3]
sorted_arr = reduce(lambda a,b : (b,a) if a > b else (a,b), arr)
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Which is expected, because my reduce function inserts a tuple into the int array, instead of 2 separate integers. And then the tuple gets compared to an int...

Is there a way to insert back 2 numbers into the list, and only run the function on every second number in the list? Or a way to swap the numbers with using reduce()?

Documentation says very little about the reduce function, so I am out of ideas right now.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce

Comment: It's possible - one way is to repeatedly reduce to find the minimum value.

Comment: Others already shown numerous way how to use `reduce` to execute *insertion sort*. I want to note that this choice is natural if you have to use `reduce`, because *insertion sort* belongs to category of so-called *online sorting alghorithms* meaning that it could work with new values appearing one-after-one (it do not need to know all values to begin work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to sort the list using `reduce`:

```
arr = [17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 5, 3]
sorted_arr = reduce(
    lambda a, b: [x for x in a if x <= b] + [b] + [x for x in a if x > b],
    arr,
    []
)
print(sorted_arr)
#[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 17]
```

At each reduce step, build a new output list which concatenates a list of all of the values less than or equal to `b`, `[b]`, and a list of all of the values greater than `b`. Use the optional third argument to `reduce` to initialize the output to an empty list.

Comment: Neat quicksort lambda.

Comment: This is not quicksort.

Comment: This is insertion sort.

Comment: Ah right. I thought `[x for x in a if x < b] + [b] + [x for x in a if x > b]` looked similar to [a Haskell implementation of quicksort](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion#quick-sort). But I see now that the principle lies in one element being *inserted* on each folding.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're misunderstanding how reduce works here. Reduce is synonymous to *right-fold* in some other languages (e.g. Haskell). The first argument expects a function which takes two parameters: an *accumulator* and an element to accumulate.

Let's hack into it:

```
arr = [17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 5, 3]
reduce(lambda xs, x: [print(xs, x), xs+[x]][1], arr, [])
```

Here, `xs` is the accumulator and `x` is the element to accumulate. Don't worry too much about `[print(xs, x), xs+[x]][1]` – it's just there to print intermediate values of `xs` and `x`. Without the printing, we could simplify the lambda to `lambda xs, x: xs + [x]`, which just appends to the list.

The above outputs:

```
[] 17
[17] 2
[17, 2] 3
[17, 2, 3] 6
[17, 2, 3, 6] 1
[17, 2, 3, 6, 1] 3
[17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3] 1
[17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1] 9
[17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9] 5
[17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 5] 3
```

As we can see, `reduce` passes an accumulated list as the first argument and a new element as the second argument.（If `reduce` is still boggling you, [*How does reduce work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108855/how-does-reduce-function-work) contains some nice explanations.)

Our particular lambda *inserts* a new element into the accumulator on each "iteration". This hints at insertion sort:

```
def insert(xs, n):
    """
    Finds first element in `xs` greater than `n` and returns an inserted element.
    `xs` is assumed to be a sorted list.
    """
    for i, x in enumerate(xs):
        if x > n:
            return xs[:i] + [n] + xs[i:]

    return xs + [n]

sorted_arr = reduce(insert, arr, [])
print(sorted_arr)
```

This prints the correctly sorted array:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 17]
```

<sup>Note that a third parameter to `reduce` (i.e. `[]`) was specified as we *initialise* the sort should with an empty list.</sup>

Comment: Can you explain the use of the `[1]` indexing? I've never used reduce before.

Comment: @pstatix `[print(xs, x), xs+[x]][1]` – this part? Here I'm just creating a list and indexing it. It's synonymous to `temp = [print(xs, x), xs + [x]]; print(temp[1])`. It doesn't mingle with reduce. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ninjad! But yes, it's an insertion sort.

```py
def insert(acc, e):
    for i, x in enumerate(acc):
        if x > e:
            acc.insert(i, e)
            return acc
    acc.append(e)
    return acc

reduce(insert, [1, 2, 6, 4, 7, 3, 0, -1], [])
```

outputs

```py
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

After some thinking I concluded that it is also possible to do swap-based sort, if you are allowed to use `reduce` more than once. Namely:

```
from functools import reduce
arr = [17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 5, 3]
def func(acc,x):
    if not acc:
        return [x]
    if acc[-1]<x:
        return acc+[x]
    else:
        return acc[:-1]+[x]+acc[-1:]

def my_sort(x):
    moresorted = reduce(func,x,[])
    print(moresorted)
    if x==moresorted:
        return moresorted
    else:
        return my_sort(moresorted)

print('arr:',arr)
arr_sorted = my_sort(arr)
print('arr sorted:',arr_sorted)
```

Output:

```
arr: [17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 5, 3]
[2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 5, 3, 17]
[2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 6, 5, 3, 9, 17]
[2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 9, 17]
[1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 17]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 17]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 17]
arr sorted: [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 17]
```

I placed `print(moresorted)` inside `func` for educational purposes, you could remove it if you wish.

Now explanation: `my_sort` is recursive function, with every run of it list become more and more sorted. `func` which is used as function in `reduce` does append new element and then swaps 2 last elements of list if they are not in ascending order.
This mean in every run of `my_sort` number "travels" rightward until in take place where next number is bigger.
`if not acc` is required for starting - notice that third argument of `reduce` is `[]` meaning that during first execution of `func` in each `reduce` first argument for func is `[]`, so asking `acc[-1]<x`? would result in error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand this
(1)Usage of Reduce is basically  to reduce the expression to a single final value
(2)reduce() stores the intermediate result and only returns the final summation value
(3)We will take the smallest element using reduce, append it to sorted_list and remove from the original list
(4)Now the reduce will work on the rest of the elements and repeat step 3 again
(5)while list_nums: will run until the list becomes empty

```
list_of_nums = [1,19,5,17,9]
sorted_list=[]
while list_of_nums:
    maxvalue=reduce(lambda x,y: x if x<y else y,list_of_nums)
    sorted_list.append(maxvalue)
    list_of_nums.remove(maxvalue)
print(sorted_list)
```

[1, 5, 9, 17, 19]

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Comment: Code-only (& link-only) responses are best left as Comments, Not Answers. While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not  a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, self-contained, complete Answers are more likely to be upvoted, and are some strengths the SO platform has, differentiating it from forums. You can `edit` to add an explanation, & to supplement your reasoning with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `lambda a,b : (b,a) if a > b else (a,b)`, which only knows how to merge two integers into a sorted tuple, you want a function which knows how to merge two sorted tuples into a sorted tuple.

This is exactly function `merge` from mergesort!

This function is already present in python's standard library, in module `heapq`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge

```py
from functools import reduce
from heapq import merge

arr = [17, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 1, 9, 5, 3]
sorted_arr = list(reduce(merge, [(x,) for x in arr]))

print(sorted_arr)
# [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 17]
```