# Why is my code for sorting a list via reduce in Python throwing an error?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, reduce, bubble-sort

I thought of a one-liner to sort a list in Python, but it hasn't been working. I thought that I could use `reduce` to go through the list and swap elements as needed, like in bubble sort. But the interpreter is being frustrating today:

```
from functools import  reduce

def reduce_sort(*lst):
    sorter = lambda x, y: y, x if x > y else x, y
    return reduce(sorter, lst)

reduce_sort(5, 4, 6, 7, 1)
```

This is giving me `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you expect this sorter to work at all…

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045986/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-list-with-reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting with `functools.reduce` is a good idea.

### Why your code currently doesn't work

However, once you start combining two or more elements from the initial list into a sorted sublist, your function `sorter = lambda x, y: y, x if x > y else x, y` is no longer adequate: it only knows how to combine two elements into a length-2 list; it doesn't know how to combine two sorted lists into a sorted list.

Example:

```py
initial list =   [17, 45, 100, 96, 29, 15, 0, 32, 4, 100, 61, 11, 85, 96, 2, 75, 88, 51, 16, 27, 68, 74, 99, 27, 83, 38, 96, 40, 73, 99, 33, 36, 86, 54, 50, 36, 44, 56, 0, 62, 62, 87, 64, 14, 63, 78, 98, 64, 60, 57, 56, 80, 80, 32, 40, 51, 64, 29, 21, 43, 63, 44, 35, 25, 37, 10, 13, 9, 34, 10, 39, 70, 14, 33, 49, 16, 80, 50, 14, 82, 51, 82, 67, 10, 20, 6, 59, 5, 31, 62, 83, 92, 13, 59, 71, 65, 1, 25, 78, 45]
began reducing = [[17, 45], [96, 100], [15, 29], [0, 32], 4, 100, 61, 11, 85, 96, 2, 75, 88, 51, 16, 27, 68, 74, 99, 27, 83, 38, 96, 40, 73, 99, 33, 36, 86, 54, 50, 36, 44, 56, 0, 62, 62, 87, 64, 14, 63, 78, 98, 64, 60, 57, 56, 80, 80, 32, 40, 51, 64, 29, 21, 43, 63, 44, 35, 25, 37, 10, 13, 9, 34, 10, 39, 70, 14, 33, 49, 16, 80, 50, 14, 82, 51, 82, 67, 10, 20, 6, 59, 5, 31, 62, 83, 92, 13, 59, 71, 65, 1, 25, 78, 45]
sorter([15, 29], [0, 32]) = ???
```

How to fix this `sorter` function? What we want is to be able to merge two sorted lists into a sorted list. Does this ring a bell? Yes! It's the `merge` function from `mergesort`.

We could implement it ourselves... Or we can look in the python standard modules if it isn't already implemented somewhere. It is. [It's called `heapq.merge`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge)

### Replacing `sorter` with `heapq.merge`

Let's replace your `sorter` with `heapq.merge`:

```py
import random
import functools
import heapq
ll = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(100)]
list(functools.reduce(heapq.merge, ll))
# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Oops! `heapq.merge` expects two iterables. Initially our list doesn't contains lists, it contains single elements. We need to replace these single elements with singleton lists or singleton tuples:

```py
import random
import functools
import heapq
ll = [(random.randint(0,100),) for i in range(100)]
list(functools.reduce(heapq.merge, ll))
# [3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 24, 25, 25, 27, 27, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 33, 33, 38, 38, 39, 39, 41, 42, 43, 43, 43, 46, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 62, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 74, 78, 79, 82, 82, 83, 83, 86, 86, 86, 86, 89, 91, 92, 93, 95, 96, 96, 96, 97, 98, 99, 99, 100, 100]
```

It works! Note the `( ,)` construct inside of `ll` that makes singleton tuples. If you don't like tuples and would prefer lists, you can use `[ ]` instead of `( ,)`.

Of course, you want to be able to sort a list that contains numbers, not singleton tuples. So let's add `lambda x: (x,)` or `lambda x: [x]` to our mix:

### The final solution

```py
import functools
import heapq
def reduce_sort(ll):
  list(functools.reduce(heapq.merge, map(lambda x: (x,), ll)))

import random
ll = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(100)]
reduce_sort(ll)
# [3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 20, 20, 24, 25, 25, 27, 27, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 33, 33, 38, 38, 39, 39, 41, 42, 43, 43, 43, 46, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 62, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 74, 78, 79, 82, 82, 83, 83, 86, 86, 86, 86, 89, 91, 92, 93, 95, 96, 96, 96, 97, 98, 99, 99, 100, 100]
```

Answer (score 4):

`sorter` is a tuple:

```
import ast

print(ast.dump(
  ast.parse("lambda x, y: y, x if x > y else x, y")
))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNCoAgGAX3nuLRSkHatImg7mJpJPjzoQZ5erM2j4FhHtVyxTDNlFqznmIqULkwdkRtsGJwyu9a4ZGoC6rEA3v22VBhXDa/GBijZEPhvRz17ekHUikb/v0IIVp7AQ)

It actually parses to this:

```
Module(body=[Expr(value=
  Tuple(elts=[
    Lambda(
      args=arguments(posonlyargs=[], args=[arg(arg='x', annotation=None, type_comment=None), arg(arg='y', annotation=None, type_comment=None)], vararg=None, kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], kwarg=None, defaults=[]),
      body=Name(id='y', ctx=Load())
    ),
    IfExp(
      test=Compare(left=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()), ops=[Gt()], comparators=[Name(id='y', ctx=Load())]),
      body=Name(id='x', ctx=Load()),
      orelse=Name(id='x', ctx=Load())
    ),
    Name(id='y', ctx=Load())
  ],
ctx=Load()))],type_ignores=[])
```

So it's equivalent to

```
sorter = (lambda x, y: y), (x if x > y else x), y
```

...where the second expression, `x if x > y else x`, will raise an exception because it doesn't know what `x` is.

You should explicitly specify that the `if` expression evaluates to tuples:

```
sorter = lambda x, y: (y, x) if x > y else (x, y)
```

Now `sorter` is a function, but the code as a whole won't work because on the second iteration of `reduce` `x` will become a tuple (one of those returned by the `if` expression) that'll be compared to `y`, which is an integer. Such operation is not possible, so you'll get another error, now at runtime.

Comment: [Not that this actually works either though…](https://repl.it/repls/ProfitableFrayedPixels)

Comment: @deceze, well, yes, because `x` - the accumulator - ends up being a tuple... I'm not sure `reduce` is the right tool here anyway

Comment: Perhaps bette include the `ast` command here, in case TIO stops working tomorrow.