# Nested loop on a list with a function

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I got stuck on that:

- a list `y = (1,2,3...)`
- a function `func(A,B)`
- a constant `C`

How can I express this situation with loops?

```
B1 = func(C , y[0])
B2 = func(B1 , y[1])
B3 = func(B2 , y[2]) #.... and so on.
```

Comment: You can do it with looks but this is exactly what `functools.reduce` does.  You're looking for `reduce(func, [C] + y)`. (You need to first do `from functools import reduce`)

Comment: For more information see: [How does reduce function work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108855/how-does-reduce-function-work/31660532)

Answer (score 2):

The first argument is just the return value of the previous call, starting with `C`:

```
result = C
for yval in y:
    result = func(result, yval)
```

As pointed out in the comments, this pattern is captured by the often overlooked `reduce` function. (Overlooked, in part, because it was demoted from the built-in namespace to the `functools` module in Python 3.)

```
from functools import reduce


result = reduce(func, y, C)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

First of all, regular loop:

```py
C = ...  # the constant
b = C
for i in y:
   b = func(b, i)
```

But using a reduce like this, is my preferred way of doing this:

```py
from functools import reduce
b = reduce(func, y, C)  # the last arg being the initial item used
```

You could also use the walrus notation, which is only useful (IMO) when saving the intermediate states.

```py
bs = [(b := func(b, yi)) for yi in y)]
b  # b being the end result
```

Comment: For the third case, there is `itertools.accumulate(y, func, initial=C)`.