# Recursive reduce function in Python

Tags: python, recursion, reduce

I'm given a sequence `tuple(range(1,5))` and I am supposed to write a recursive function with reduce to calculate the product 1*2*3*4*5 = 24.

I don't know how to do this recursively. I've tried looking here https://www.burgaud.com/foldl-foldr-python/ and understand reduce is left-fold. My non-recursive implementation is simply:

```py
def red(func, seq):
    return reduce(func, seq)

red(lambda x, y: x*y, tuple(range(1,5)))
```

As reduce is left fold, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you supposed to implement a recursive function that mimicks reduce or actually uses reduce? Right now, your function red is not recusive, because it doesn't call itself.

Comment: If you're using `reduce`, you don't need recursion. If you use recursion, you don't need `reduce`.

Comment: Oh I realize I might have missunderstood, I think the idea might be to mimic reduce!

Answer (score 2):

To make a function recursive, you need to add a case for termination (only one element left) and the recursive call in which you make the problem smaller (go one step ahead in the sequence)

```
def reduce(func, seq):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return seq[0]
    return func(seq[0], reduce(func, seq[1:]))


print(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, tuple(range(1, 5))))
```

Output:

```
24
```

If you're using python 3.10+, you should look into pattern matching for a more functional style in python.

Comment: Ah I see!! I see another mistake I made was assuming recursion requires us to start from the end -> beginning. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: The blog you linked in your question has good information on foldl and foldr. The order in which things are computed depends on the implementation of the recursion. Look up tail-recursive vs recursive and if you really want to get into it, Continuation-passing style is a fascinating concept

Comment: Hi! I looked over it again, and I believe the suggested/accepted solution multiplies the arguments in the incorrect order. If we change the lambda function to `lambda x, y: x*y*y, tuple(range(1, 5))`, we should recieve 1*4*9*16 = 576. But the current solution takes the arguments in the wrong order. Instead I believe the correct order of recursion to be achieved when swapping to `return func(seq[-1], reduce(func, seq[:-1]))`

Comment: After actually revisiting it again I believe the suggested solution is wrong. I say this as I did some test comparisons with `reduce` from functools. For instance;

`print(myreduce(lambda x, y: x-y, range(1,6)))
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x-y, range(1,6)))
`
## Output ##

11
-13

Comment: @OLGJ if you want to unwind the recursion the other way to preserve order, just do something like `return func(reduce(func, seq[:-1]), seq[-1])` This should match `functors.reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

The prior [answer by Tobi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71067203/) will not work with an iterable input which is a standard expectation for `reduce`. This answer however will. It is adapted from a [non-recursive implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109065/).

```
def reducer(func, iterable):
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77298563
    iterable = iter(iterable)  # Required for supporting `list` or `tuple` or `range` input.

    try:
        result = next(iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        raise TypeError('reduce() of empty iterable')

    try:
        return func(result, reducer(func, iterable))
    except TypeError:
        return result
```

Better yet, to avoid calling `iter(iterable)` repeatedly, an inner function can be used:

```py
def reducer(func, iterable):
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77298563
    iterable = iter(iterable)  # Required for supporting `list` or `tuple` or `range` input.

    def inner(start, iterator):
        try:
            next_ = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            return start
        new_start = func(start, next_)
        return inner(new_start, iterator)

    try:
        first = next(iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        raise TypeError('reduce() of empty iterable')
    return inner(first, iterable)
```

Usage examples:

```
> reducer(lambda i,j: i+j, range(1))
0

> reducer(lambda i,j: i+j, range(100))
4950

> reducer(lambda x, y: x*y, range(1,5))  # Example in question.
24
```